# Android, How to support tablets?

Tags: android, drawable

In my application I support ldpi, mdpi and hdpi mpbile phones. therefore I have three drawable folders to support these smart phones.

Everything is fine when I check the result on mobile phones but the problem is showing in G.Tab 7". When I run the application on this tablet, the size of application is not feet on the screen. Size of my application is as same size as SII in the middle of screen and margins are black. some thing like below image.

Do I need to add another folder in drawable? If yes what should the name of this folder be?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What folders do you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this documentation article: [How to Support Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support). Specifically pay attention to [`<supports-screens>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html).